# What devices are necessary for mobile app development?

Tags: testing, web-applications, ios7, mobile-webkit, iphone-web-app

I'm developing a 3D application with css3 and webgl for ios6+ and android 4.0+ (mainly for mobile phone). The devices I have are iPhone 4S(iOS7), iPad mini2 and nexus 5.

So is **necessary for me to have an iPhone 5S** or any other devices to do the test?

Any **suggestions for device testing** to target as more devices?

Is there any **common compatibility issues** between iOS safari, android Chrome and android browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you may also consider a Nexus 7 or Nexus 10 for Android tablet testing. There are loads of other large screen Android devices but you may have already known that the Nexus series are most suitable for development.

Comment: Is an iPhone 5S necessary? Or iPhone 5c?

Comment: I have not developed iOS apps before so I'am not sure if the increased resolution and screen size on iPhone 5s/5c takes any effect. But if you decide to get an iPhone 5 series I suppose a 5c would be enough.